# Create image with Packer Google Compute Builder but without project users baked in (cloud-init)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, packer, cloud-init, hashicorp-packer

I'm using Google Compute Builder to create packer image:

```
source "googlecompute" "github-runner" {
  image_name          = "github-runner-${replace(var.runner_version, ".", "-")}-v${var.custom_version}"
  image_family        = "github-runner"
  project_id          = "xxx"
  source_image_family = "ubuntu-2004-lts"
  ssh_username        = "packer"
  use_internal_ip     = true
  zone                = "europe-west4-c"
}

build {
  sources = [
    "source.googlecompute.github-runner"
  ]
}
```

However because of cloud-init, all project users get provisioned inside the builder VM and as a result inside the final image.

Is there any option to skip creating project's users on the builder VM?

Comment: The Account Management feature of [`guest-agent`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/guest-agent) (except when OS Login is used) is responsible for provisioning accounts. You can disable this in the agent's config (`accounts_daemon`). If you don't want the agent installed, you may have to create an image from scratch.

Comment: Two links that help explain this: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/restrict-ssh-keys and https://docs.bridgecrew.io/docs/bc_gcp_networking_8

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to add `block-project-ssh-keys = "true"` to metadata. Final declaration:

```
source "googlecompute" "github-runner" {
  image_name          = "github-runner-${replace(var.runner_version, ".", "-")}-v${var.custom_version}"
  image_family        = "github-runner"
  project_id          = "xxx"
  source_image_family = "ubuntu-2004-lts"
  ssh_username        = "packer"
  use_internal_ip     = true
  zone                = "europe-west4-c"
  metadata = {
    block-project-ssh-keys = "true"
  }
}

build {
  sources = [
    "source.googlecompute.github-runner"
  ]
}
```